# What is the use of enemy's portal key

Tags: ingress

I'm new to ingress and I'm totally confused about the items in my inventory. Recently I hacked few resistance portals and I got their portal keys I know what to do with my own keys and I know that I can't link to an enemy's portal.So my question is  What is the use of enemy's portal key in ingress??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So keys are for portals, not just enemy's. The keys are used in order for you to link portals that your team has taken over. Without a key, you cannot link a portal to another. Let's say you get a key for portal A, you are now able to link portal B to portal A. Now you will not be able to link portal A to portal B unless you have a key for it (but if you have created the link from B to A then the link exists and you don't have to worry). A key is usually acquired after hacking a portal a couple of times, between 4 to 6 from what I have experienced.

Comment: I belive the confusion is on getting keys to portals that are owned by the enemy. The thing about this is, that the portals won't always be owned by the enemy. The game is a constant struggle over the ownership of those portals and they get switched between teams rather easily. You can't use the keys while the enemy controls the portals, but you can use them once you team has taken control of them.

Comment: Ah yes. I thought that's what the confusion was about. Well said.

Comment: IIRC, you can use the key to monitor the portal's status remotely.  I know it works on friendly portals;  you can see when the resonators are weak and, if friendly, recharge them remotely with the key.  If you can use the portal key to monitor an enemy portal, you'll know the precise time to strike. :D

Comment: @gatherer818 the portal remote view works on every portal, so yes, keys can also be used to monitor the enemy's activity